# Extract multiple integers from a String in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, split, jsoup

I have a single String in the following format(Output from Jsoup)

```
[<ul>
<li><span></span><a, rel="nofollow"><span>Afterword</span></a></li>
<li><span></span><a, rel="nofollow"><span>MW, Chapter, 2255</span></a></li>
<li><span></span><a, rel="nofollow"><span>MW, Chapter, 2254</span></a></li> 
<li><span></span><a, rel="nofollow"><span>MW, Chapter, 2253</span></a></li> 
<li><span></span><a, rel="nofollow"><span>MW, Chapter, 2252</span></a></li> 
</ul>]
```

I want to extract the integers such as 2255, 2254 etc from this String.

I used various options I found here but none of them worked. The solutions so far gives me just the digits all banded together.

I am open to use Jsoup or split for this.

Please help.

Comment: Try to use Pattern and Regex.

Comment: I found a simple solution online with regex which i have shared down below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63171398/919177

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution online which worked for me. sharing it here for others:

```
val p = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
val m = p.matcher(stringUnderTest)
while (m.find()) {
  println(m.group())
}
```

Answer (score 6):

it is quite simple using regular expressions https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/

```kotlin
    val string = "[<ul>\n" +
            "<li><span></span><a, rel=\"nofollow\"><span>Afterword</span></a></li>\n" +
            "<li><span></span><a, rel=\"nofollow\"><span>MW, Chapter, 2255</span></a></li>\n" +
            "<li><span></span><a, rel=\"nofollow\"><span>MW, Chapter, 2254</span></a></li> \n" +
            "<li><span></span><a, rel=\"nofollow\"><span>MW, Chapter, 2253</span></a></li> \n" +
            "<li><span></span><a, rel=\"nofollow\"><span>MW, Chapter, 2252</span></a></li> \n" +
            "</ul>]"

    val regex = Regex("\\d+")
    val resultList = regex.findAll(string).map { it.value }.toList()
    println(resultList) //prints [2255, 2254, 2253, 2252]
```

Comment: Note that that will find _all_ groups of digits, even if they're within tags or attributes (e.g. it would extract 2 from `<h2>`, and 120 from `<p style="font-size:120%;">`).  As long as OP doesn't need to handle those cases differently, then this is a good simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

I tried extracting the text directly using JSoup but you're right in that everything just gets bunched together and you end up with a single string that includes everything which is less easy to work with.

Taking a step back then, you can instead get all the potentially relevant Elements using `doc.select("ul li span")`. From there, you can filter the elements which contain text starting with `MW` and then from there, take the text, split it, using `", "` as a delimiter, to get an array and take the last element of the result (the integer). I parsed this to an Integer by wrapping the result using `Integer.parseInt` which you can remove if you just want the `String` value.

Finally the results that are filtered and mapped to the correct value are collected to a list.

```java
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class JSoupExtract {

    public static final String input = "<ul>" +
            "<li><span></span><a, rel=\"nofollow\"><span>Afterword</span></a></li>" +
            "<li><span></span><a, rel=\"nofollow\"><span>MW, Chapter, 2255</span></a></li>" +
            "<li><span></span><a, rel=\"nofollow\"><span>MW, Chapter, 2254</span></a></li>" +
            "<li><span></span><a, rel=\"nofollow\"><span>MW, Chapter, 2253</span></a></li>" +
            "<li><span></span><a, rel=\"nofollow\"><span>MW, Chapter, 2252</span></a></li>" +
            "</ul>";                       // TOKEN_ID = 0^  1^       2^
    public static final int INT_TOKEN_ID = 2;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
        Elements elements = doc.select("ul li span");
        List<Integer> result = elements.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.text() != null && e.text().startsWith("MW"))
                .map(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.text().split(", ")[INT_TOKEN_ID]))
                .collect(toList());

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

output:

```java
[2255, 2254, 2253, 2252]
```

Comment: It's obviously more complex (and less efficient) to treat the input as HTML than as a simple text string (for which a regex is a nice solution), but this is a much safer and more powerful solution, coping with a much wider range of inputs with fewer surprises.